# Flutter Adding QR Reader To Bottom Tab Bar

Tags: flutter

I am trying to add QR reader to bottom tab bar , but when i switch tab to another one , the qr reader still reads from Camera

Comment: Please add a code snippet what you have achieved so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try pause the camera when you load the other tab inside the method initState().